# Saving variable sizes over loops in Julia with varinfo

Tags: julia

I'm trying to see how the size of variables I'm working with increase over each iteration of a loop. I'm not sure which variables are increasing in size, so I would like to capture all of them. To do so I would like to use `varinfo()`, but as this outputs a Markdown table I'm not able to access it. Is there a way to either convert the Markdown table to a more useable format, or else save the size of variables in the environment in general?

Ideally, I would like as output a dataframe with as many rows or columns as the number of loops, and the size of each variable in each corresponding loop saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like your idea for debugging purposes :-)

This code is inspired by: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/src/InteractiveUtils.jl

```
using  DataFrames

function debug_list_vals(m::Module=Main)
    res = DataFrame()
    vs = [v for v in sort!(names(m)) if isdefined(m, v)]
    for v in vs
        value = getfield(m, v)
        if !(value===Base || value===Main || value===Core ||
            value===InteractiveUtils || value===debug_list_vals)
            append!(res, DataFrame(v=v,size=Base.summarysize(value),
                                    summary=summary(value)))
        end
    end
    res
end
```

Now let's give it a spin:

```
julia> for i in 1:3
           push!(some_array, i)
           println("i=$i ::", debug_list_vals())
       end
i=1 ::2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ v          │ size  │ summary                  │
│     │ Symbol     │ Int64 │ String                   │
├─────┼────────────┼───────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ ans        │ 48    │ 1-element Array{Int64,1} │
│ 2   │ some_array │ 48    │ 1-element Array{Int64,1} │
i=2 ::2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ v          │ size  │ summary                  │
│     │ Symbol     │ Int64 │ String                   │
├─────┼────────────┼───────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ ans        │ 56    │ 2-element Array{Int64,1} │
│ 2   │ some_array │ 56    │ 2-element Array{Int64,1} │
i=3 ::2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ v          │ size  │ summary                  │
│     │ Symbol     │ Int64 │ String                   │
├─────┼────────────┼───────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ ans        │ 64    │ 3-element Array{Int64,1} │
│ 2   │ some_array │ 64    │ 3-element Array{Int64,1} │
```

Comment: This is fantastic, and works exactly as intended! A massive timesaver for debugging